# Protobuf-net - The stream does not support concurrent IO read or write operations

Tags: vb.net, memory, httpwebrequest, http-post, protobuf-net

I have a program in VB.Net (v2.0 framework) and while doing http post from a sql data reader, I am getting the following error on few machines:

```
System.NotSupportedException: The stream does not support concurrent IO read or write operations.
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.InternalWrite(Boolean async, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoWriter.Flush(ProtoWriter writer)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoWriter.Dispose()
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoWriter.System.IDisposable.Dispose()
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(Stream dest, Object value, Type type, PrefixStyle style, Int32 fieldNumber, SerializationContext context)
   at ProtoBuf.Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix[T](Stream destination, T instance, PrefixStyle style, Int32 fieldNumber)
   at ProtoBuf.Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix[T](Stream destination, T instance, PrefixStyle style)
```

Code:

```
    postStream = request.GetRequestStream()
        While dr.Read()
           dd.Add(dr) ' Adding data row to proto
           ProtoBuf.Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(Of DataDump)(postStream, dd, ProtoBuf.PrefixStyle.Base128) ' stream proto to http post stream
           dd.Clear() ' Clear proto 
        End While
 response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Protobuf-net *does not issue* concurrent read or write operations. Since you mention request streams, I expect the actual problem is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14108999/error-the-stream-does-not-support-concurrent-io-read-or-write-operations).

Comment: Please see the edit in the code.  I do getresponse only after reading all rows and serialize to postStream.  I also tried solution at https://support.microsoft.com/kb/908573/en-us

Comment: One more thing, during execution it starts taking lot of memory and eventually reaches cap of 1 GB (32 bit) and prints the stack trace.  It only happens on few machines like 5%.  On rest of machines, no issues.

Comment: @guarav well, what is it that you are serializing? How big is it? There are also ways to tweak the model to help it use forwards-only mechanisms, but unfortunately then"withlengthprefix" introduces problems; the way it does this internally is to serialize to an in-memory buffer, then write the size, then dump the buffer.

Comment: I am running a query in sqlserver, getting results via data reader, looping data reader and serialize each row with protobuf-net and sending it to http web request to a remote server.  The size of the result is definitely large.  proto model is a dictonary of type string, string so its like a key value pair of column name and row value

Comment: Actually proto itself is not large because I am creating new proto for each row and clearing it after sent to poststream.  Basically there are millions of proto streamed to httpwebrequest.  Do you think in-memory buffer will still be a problem?

Comment: @gaurav46 that is really hard to answer without lots of context

Comment: I just did a small test.  Instead of doing http post stream, I just wrote the protos to a file via file stream.  It worked!!  No memory issue too.  So looks like the httpwebrequest is doing something.

Comment: @gaurav awesome to hear! Well, sort of. At least it gets you a few steps closer : knowing what it *isn't* is half the job :)

Comment: Absolutely.  I had suspected that and tried the solution in support.microsoft.com/kb/908573/en-us but still it doesnt work.

Comment: In the end, it is not a protbuf-net related issue at all.  Even after saving the protos in binary file and then trying to upload, it throws the error.
It might be httpwebrequest, .net or windows patch or sophos antivirus.
I am closing this question as it has gone in different tangent.
Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, it is not a protbuf-net related issue at all.  Even after saving the protos in binary file and then trying to upload, it throws the error.
It might be httpwebrequest, .net or windows patch or sophos antivirus.
I am closing this question as it has gone in different tangent.
Thanks for all your help.